# Linq распечатать содержание массива

Tags: c#, linq

Задача: каждый элемент массива вставить в строку. Хочу сделать это с использованием Linq
Что то не могу понять как заставить это работать правильно?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {

        string[] id = { "1", "2", "3" };

        string result =  $"Some data {id.Select( item => item )}";

        Console.WriteLine( result );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам нужно объединить элементы массива в строку, то есть более подходящий способ, чем LINQ:

```
String.Join(", ", id);
```

Если всё же необходимо использовать LINQ, то можно воспользоваться [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
id.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

Получившуюся в результате агрегации строку можете использовать в форматной строке.